# Получить значение текстового поля по нажатию на поле

Tags: jquery

Подскажите как решить такую задачку:?

**Создайте 3 блока с id: id_1, id_2 и id_3.**

**Создайте текстовое поле, в которое пользователь должен ввести число 1, 2 или 3.**

**Создайте кнопку «Удалить».**

**После нажатия по кнопке «Удалить», спрячьте через hide() в jQuery блок с id=id_введённое_число. Например, если пользователь ввёл 2, то должен исчезнуть блок id_2**

Решить спомощью jquery. Чето вообще не могу понять как сделать?

p/s

```
<div id="id_1" onclick="$('#test').hide()">1111111</div>
<div id="id_2" onclick="$('#test').hide()">2222222</div>
<div id="id_3" onclick="$('#test').hide()">3333333</div>
<input type="text" value="" id="text"/>     
<input type="submit" value="Удалить" id="button" 
onclick="
var element=$('text');
var text = element.val();
alert(text);
"/>
```

Вот, что, я не могу получить значение текстового поля по нажатию на поле!

Comment: @duddeniska, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: onclick="alert($('text').val())"

И тип у кнопки сделайте button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/XDM7C/

```
<div class="box" id="id_1"></div>
<div class="box" id="id_2"></div>
<div class="box" id="id_3"></div>
<input type="text" id="it">
<input type="button" value="remove" onclick="document.getElementById('id_' + it.value).style.display = 'none'">
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/m6mjK/1/

-- Молодец, Иванов! Садись, пять!

-- Ну что Вы, Пал Палыч, за 2 минуты написал =)))

Comment: @mountpoint, Не, надо было всё в onclick запихнуть:

    <input type="submit" value="Удалить" id="button" onclick='(function() {
        var val = $("input[type=text]").val();    
        if(isNaN(val)) { alert("Введите число"); return; }    
        $("#id_" + val).hide(1000);
    })()' />

Comment: >> не надо было всё в onclick запихнуть

что-то я вас не понял. может вы запятую где-то пропустили?))

Comment: Ага, добавил запятую.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="bl1">Блок 1</div>
<div id="bl2">Блок 2</div>
<div id="bl3">Блок 3</div>
<input type="number" min="1" max="3" step="1" name="nomer" id="nomer">
<input type="button" name="btn" value="Видалити" onclick="$('#bl' + $('#nomer').val()).hide();">
```

Comment: Бррр.. Использовать onclick при jQuery...